# There has to be a better way to check for certain known numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have project going that contains a lot more numbers than shows in my code below but would like to know a better way of checking to see if certain numbers are in any of the lines of text in a richtextbox. I only list 3 numbers here but there are many more. The code does work but surely there is a better way.

```
For i As Integer = RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        ' Get the line
        Dim line As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(i)

        ' Search and find numbers 1, 2, 3 etc.
        Dim index As Integer = line.IndexOf("1")
        Dim index2 As Integer = line.IndexOf("2")
        Dim index3 As Integer = line.IndexOf("3")

        ' If found the match 1
        If index <> -1 Then
          ' Do code
        End If

        ' If found the match 2
        If index2 <> -1 Then
          ' Do code
        End If

        ' If found the match 3
        If index3 <> -1 Then
          ' Do code
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and a relevant answer requires more information such as: 1) is line found on and position found at relevant to `Do Code`, 2) does number occurrences greater than one have any significance and 3) does the information processed by `Do Code` vary based on the value found, if so how?.   There are probably other considerations as well, but as it stands now, you need to provide more information as to what your definition of **better** is.

Comment: `the do code does not matter to get this to work.`. In thise case the question is off-topic for SO. You better put it on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)